# How show the last status of a mobile number and old data in the same row ? using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working in a telecom and part of work is to check the last status for a specific  mobile  number along with that last `de-active` status,it's easy to get the active number by using the condition `ACTIVE` int the statement ,but it's not easy to pick the last `de-active` status because each number might have more than one `de-active` status or only one status `ACTIVE`, I use the `EXP_DATE` as an indicator for the last de-active status,I want to show both new data and old data in one row,but I'm struggling with that ,below my table and my expected result :-

[image: My current table]

my expected result

[image]

query that I use on daily basis

`select * from test where exp_date>sysdate;` to get the active numbers , to get the de-active number `select * from test where exp_date<sysdate;`

Comment: Please show the SQL query you have used to obtain the results.

Comment: `select * from test where exp_date>sysdate;` to get the active numbers , to get the de-active number `select * from test where exp_date<sysdate;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do `outer join` with one subquery containing `ACTIVE` records and one with latest `DE-ACTIVE` record as following:

```
SELECT A.MSISDN, 
A.NAME, 
A.SUB_STATUS,
A.CREATED_DATE, 
A.EXP_DATE,
D.MSISDN AS MSISDN_, 
D.NAME AS OLD_NAME, 
D.SUB_STATUS OLD_STATUS, 
D.CREATED_DATE AS OLD_CREATED_DATE, 
D.EXP_DATE AS OLD_EXP_DATE
FROM
(SELECT * FROM TEST 
    WHERE EXP_DATE > SYSDATE
     AND SUB_STATUS = 'ACTIVE') A -- ACTIVE RECORD 
     -- USE CONDITION TO FETCH ACTIVE RECORD AS PER YOUR REQUIREMENT
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT T.*, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.MSISDN ORDER BY EXP_DATE DESC NULLS LAST) AS RN
    FROM TEST T 
   WHERE T.EXP_DATE < SYSDATE
     AND T.SUB_STATUS='DE-ACTIVE') 
     -- USE CONDITION TO FETCH DEACTIVE RECORD AS PER YOUR REQUIREMENT
 WHERE RN = 1
) D
ON (A.MSISDN = D.MSISDN)
```

Cheers!!

Comment: By the way I changed the join type from `outer join` to `FULL OUTER JOIN` in Oracle .

Comment: Yes, I meant `FULL OUTER JOIN` only!! but missed it as I gave answer from mobile browser. anyway, updated the answer with `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Comment: Can you explain to me how the second query works please,`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.MSISDN ORDER BY EXP_DATE DESC NULLS LAST) AS RN`, `ROW_NUMBER()` ?, `PARTION BY T.MSISDN`, `NULLS LAST` ?

Comment: It will give numbers to each row. Numbers will restart for each `MSISDN`(as it is in `PARTITION BY`) and numbers will be given in order of `EXP_DATE` in a descending manner.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an overview of how to do this -- one query to get a distinct list of all the phone numbers, left join to a list of the most recent active on that phone number,left join to a list of the most recent de-active on the phone number

Comment: Thanks, that's mean I have to upload the the list of numbers in one table let's call it `mobile_numbers` then left join on another the first query for active numbers,then left join on the second query for de-active numbers ,but wait how I will pick up the last de-active status for each number ? each number might have more than de-active status I need the last one based on the EXP_DATE .

Comment: you use group by

Comment: yes I agree group by think it will help , I will try that .

Comment: I tried the group by at the first glance it's seems good idea,but after trying it it's returning duplicate records for the same number because it will be `group by name,sub_status,create_date,exp_date`, I think I should take into account to learn `PL/SQL` to avoid the complexity .

Comment: @OsamaAl-Banna -- you should not group by all the columns

Answer (score 1):

How about conditional aggregation?

```
select msidn,
       max(case when status = 'DE-ACTIVE' then create_date end) as deactive_date,
       max(case when status = 'ACTIVE' then exp_date end) as active_date
from test 
group by msisdn
```

Comment: then left join this back to the table to get the rest of the columns ... twice

Comment: gordon see OP's comment about exp date on my answer.

Comment: @gardon thanks , I will try your answer as well, I don't have DB access now,tomorrow I will try all the scenarios .

Comment: @OsamaAl-Banna -- remember you use a diffferent date for deactive so it would look like this: `max(case when status = 'DE-ACTIVE' then EXP_DATE end) as deactive_date`

Comment: @Hogan . . . Thank you for that clarification.